# Laravel route strange behavior

Tags: laravel, parameters, routes

The following code

```
Route::get('test/{n}', function ($n) {
    return $n;
});

App::missing(function () {
    return Response::make("Dude, that's a 404 !", 404);
});
```

works with anything like

```
http://localhost/myproject/public/test/something
```

but

```
http://localhost/myproject/public/test/
```

redirects to

```
http://localhost/test
```

I believe it should instead display

```
Dude, that's a 404 !
```

I might have missearched the SO forum, but does anyone have an explanation on this strange behavior ?

**EDIT : @Mohammad Walid**

Okay, so, I changed my routes.php to this :

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@showWelcome');

Route::get('test', function () {
    return 'test';
});

App::missing(function () {
    return Response::make("Dude, that's a 404 !", 404);
});
```

I **have not** removed the line you talked about in `public/.htaccess`.

This works :

```
base_url/test
```

But this doesn't (redirects to `localhost/test`) :

```
base_url/test/
```

How can that be, since you said that removing the line would remove that feature ?

**EIDT 2 :**

Since it turns out that the problem comes from MAMP not interpreting the trailing slashes redirect condition correctly, a bug report was created in the MAMP bug base :

http://bugs.mamp.info/view.php?id=4586

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its' because Laravel by default redirects trailing slashes.

In **app/public/.htaccess** file you can find the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301] #This line causes the problem

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Change it to:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Have a look at [trailing slashes discussion](http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=6623).

**Note** if you remove the previous line your application won't be able to handle trailing slashes.
Ex. if you have a route

```
Route::get('test', function() {
    return 'test';
}
```

Assume `base_url/test/` has been requested instead of `base_url/test` the server will respond with 404 status.

**Update**

It seems that this is an issue only happens in local development (I use XAMPP).

The expected result for that rule is the following:

```
.htaccess
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

Input (request)
http://localhost/website/test/

Output (after redirect)
http://localhost/website/test
```

But what we actually have in local development:

```
.htaccess
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

Input (request)
http://localhost/website/test/

Output (after redirect)
http://localhost/test #this is wrong, according to the rule above it should redirects to http://localhost/website/test
```

So what you'll have if you remove the rule:

```
Request
http://localhost/website/test

Response
test


Request
http://localhost/website/test/

Response
Status 404
Dude, that's a 404 !

The expected response:
test
```

That's what I meant by

> your application won't be able to handle trailing slashes.
>
> the server will respond with 404 status.

I have tested the rule with [online htaccess tester](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) and it worked as expected, that's why I suppose the problem only exists in local development.
[image: Online test snapshot]

Comment: Sorry I sent the comment too quickly, I was editing it as I have fully understood your reply and I am trying to write a comment where I would explain how I don't understand it (if this makes sense to you). I will mark it as solved as soon as I understand it all, give me five minutes to phrase another comment and explain my misunderstandings a bit better :)

Comment: @user3856210 sure, take your time.

Comment: Wow, couldn't expect a better answer :D Thanks so much ! If I could give you two ups instead of one, I would !! Thanks again for the time you spent answering my question :) PS: I just tested on the online tester, using the whole .htaccess, and as expected, it works :)

Comment: @user3856210 glad that was helpful for u :)

Comment: PS2: you're right, in MAMP, if I test the htaccess in a separate test folder, it has the same behavior, so the problem comes from there !