# Trailing slash redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mamp, trailing-slash

Following a [bug report in MAMP](http://bugs.mamp.info/view.php?id=4586), initiated by [another SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25568738/laravel-route-strange-behavior), I would like to ask how one would counter this bug where MAMP 3.0.6 (latest version) does not behave correctly with the following .htaccess rule :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

should redirect anything like

```
http://localhost/foo/test/
```

to

```
http://localhost/foo/test
```

but redirects to

```
http://localhost/test/
```

instead.

Thanks, and kind regards !

Comment: Are you setting a `RewriteBase` anywhere? If you are, what happens if you drop it, and if you're not, what happens if you set it to `/`?

Comment: I don't have have a rewrite base. I added the one you provided, but that didn't work, sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=302,L,NE]
```

Also keep in mind that if `/foo/test` is a real directory then trailing slash will be added by `mod_dir` unless you have `DirectorySlash off` in your .htaccess.

**PS: This is tested on MAMP 3.0.2.**

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) Unfortunately, that didn't work. I have a simple folder in my MAMP directory that only contains a .htaccess and nothing else. Putting the above in the .htaccess does not change  MAMP's behavior :/

Comment: Then you're not setting it up right as it is working with exact same MAMP 3.0 on my side. Make sure you place it in `DocumentRoot/.htaccess` (not in any random folder). And do read what I mentioned below my rules also.

Comment: What do you mean by DocumentRoot folder ? If I work on a project under "htdocs/test", would you consider "htdocs/test" as the root folder or "htdocs" ? I know this is a dumb question, but I'm just making sure we're talking about the same thing :)

Comment: `DocumentRoot` is set in your `Apache config`. Most likely it would be `htdocs` folder but better to check in `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf` file.

Comment: Another way to check is to create a file called `info.php` with this code `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and then open `http://localhost/info.php` to check what is its `DOCUMENT_ROOT` value.

Comment: I checked. DocumentRoot is `htdocs`. I placed a `.htaccess` in there with your code. No success :( I swear I'm trying my best !

Comment: Well I have also tried my best. But your question/comments are not giving my any clue to help you further.

Comment: It's alright, thanks for the time you spent helps, that was very nice of you :) I'll keep trying to find out what's not right and if I find I will update my question with the solution :) Thanks again !